# How to enable direct printing capabilities for web based application?

Tags: javascript, css, printing

I'm developing a web application where user require to print a particular form with a single click. Based on my findings I understand that we need to create a printable version of the form and then send it to the printer.

But still I could not find out a way to send such *printable version of the form* directly to printer without displaying the generated form to user. Appreciate any suggestions from you.

Thank You

Comment: I'm not sure if this requirement is technically possible. COnsider this: if one click (presumably on the page) was possible, then zero clicks on the page would also be sufficient - it has to be Javascript. That would mean that any malware site could force itself to be printed, and probably more than once. If you thought popup and popudner windows were bad, this would be _far_ worse.

Comment: Actually, it's quite easy iff you are in an intranet situation where the printers are in the network. Your server-side code sends the document to the printer.

Comment: @DOK, valid point, I would try out your approach as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this by loading the print view into a hidden iframe and issuing the `.print()` javascript command

Comment: I should add that this just pops up the default Print dialog. It does not send it direct to printer - which is impossible for obvious reasons.

Comment: Thankz Jami, I tried your way, it works fine and pop up dialog would rather better approach than direct printing.

Answer (score 2):

This is the code you need:

```
 <img src="print_button.jpg"  onClick="window.print()" alt="Print this page" style="cursor: pointer;">
```

You will also need to make a print css file that will style the printed page and to put this in the header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" type="text/css" href="print.css" />
```

That should take care of what you need.

Comment: But you still get a popup print dialog box, don't you?

Comment: You do, but you absolutely should.  As a developer you don't know which printer the user wants to use or if they actually want to print.  You should never force your users to do things they don't want to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you can print from the server to a designated printer (i.e., you're in an intranet), you can do something like this. There's more code than you want to see here -- get the full code [here.](http://aspalliance.com/462_Printing_an_ASPNET_Web_Form_When_It_Is_Submitted.all) **The key is that you nave a network printer** configured with permissions for ASPNET (or the account it's running under) to print to it.

I have done this. In fact, we were printing so much that we moved the printing from the web server to a web service or Windows service on another machine, to get the load off the web server.

```
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;

PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument();
// set the printer name
doc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printerName;
// print the page
doc.Print();
```